# Failed to execute write on Document warning

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, laravel-5

I am making an Angular Laravel web app, I am also using a Google map. And I am getting this warning on my console:

Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Last week it wasn't there, I wasn't able to track when this warning came. But as I was searching the web for the reason, everybody says it's caused by having a document.write() statement within the code, the problem is I don't have any document.write() statement on my code. My question is, are there any other reasons that might have caused this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is how I do the map:

First I include this on my html

Then I'm using the angular-ui google map here is the partial for it:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' refresh="{{ mapRefresh }}" zoom='map.zoom' control="map.control" events="mapEvents" options="map.options">
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: show us how the maps-API will be loaded

Comment: Well, the Google Map API has a document.write action as one of the first things it does.

Comment: I've edited the post. By the way, I've been doing it like that and I only got that warning last week which is why it's strange.